# What does node --nocrankshaft do?

Tags: node.js, v8

What does running Node.JS with `node --nocrankshaft` actually do? Is there any documentation on these types of v8 settings options in node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This disables the Crankshaft compiler.

> ...By using aggressive optimizations, Crankshaft dramatically improves
>   the performance of compute-intensive JavaScript applications - often
>   by more than a factor of two!...

Have a look at: [A New Crankshaft for V8](http://blog.chromium.org/2010/12/new-crankshaft-for-v8.html)

For more details: [a closer look at crankshaft, v8's optimizing compiler](http://wingolog.org/archives/2011/08/02/a-closer-look-at-crankshaft-v8s-optimizing-compiler)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any documentation on these types of v8 settings options in
>   node?

The `--v8-options` flag can list all the settings related to **V8**:

```
$ nodejs --v8-options

Options:
  --use_strict (enforce strict mode)
        type: bool  default: false
  --es5_readonly (activate correct semantics for inheriting readonliness)
        type: bool  default: true
  --es52_globals (activate new semantics for global var declarations)
        type: bool  default: true
  ...
```

The list contains all the flags related to V8, a short description of what each flag does, type information and default value.

The list is also available online here: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/doc/node.1. Most of the parameters of this list correspond to [V8 flags](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/flag-definitions.h).